# How to get a mysql row based on clicking dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

```
id    name     phone_number
=========================
1  || Ameer  || 9999999999
2  || Balaji || 8888888888
3  || Kumar  || 5555555555
```

```
<select class="form-control" name="name">
  <option>Ameer</option>
  <option>Balaji</option>
  <option>Kumar</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="phone">
```

so my required is when I click the select tag name get the same row phone number value and placed to be the textbox, How can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js></script>

<select class="form-control" name="name">
<?php 
    $query = "SELECT name, phone_number FROM your_table ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row->phone_numer.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>

<input type="text" name="phone"> 

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){       
        $('select[name="name"]').change( function() {
            var phone = $(this).val();
            $('input[name="phone"]').val(phone);
        });     
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using mysqli? Why not PDO?